# How to manipulate a returned array of values

Tags: java, arrays

So, I'm having a little trouble.  I finally decided what I want to do, but as soon as I was done I was like... Well... Here is what I want to do with this information, but how can I get it out of the array?

So, I return my String array 'results' with two values of fullName and pinCode in it.  I called the method to create this information using 'greeting( scan )', but now I don't know how I can take the fullName and pinCode out separately, or put those into a local array in the main method.  Any suggestions?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    greeting( scan );
}
public static String[] greeting( Scanner scan ) throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println( "Hello, User..." );

    //Timeout for 0.5 seconds
    Thread.sleep(0500);

    //Ask for the users first name
    System.out.println( "Please enter your first name: " );
    String firstName = scan.nextLine();

    //Ask for the users last name
    System.out.println( "Please enter your last name: " );
    String lastName = scan.nextLine();

    //Generates a random number between 1000-10000 for the PIN code
    String pinCode = Integer.toString((int) ((Math.random()*9000)+1000));

    //Erase everything, but letters by calling my stringValid method
    String fullName = stringValid( firstName, lastName );

    String[] results = {fullName, pinCode};
    return results;
}
```

Comment: 1st two lines are really not required ! Moreover what is the actual Problem you are facing ?

Comment: why sleep for half a second

Comment: consider making a class that has two attributes, fullname and pincode and then instantiate and return this class

Comment: (0500)-- is not half second.  It became octal notation. is that intentional

Comment: @Jayan based uppon his comment of `//Timeout for 0.5 seconds` I would guess not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that if:

```
String[] result = greeting(scan);
```

then:

```
String fullName = result[0];
String pinCode = result[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    greeting( scan );
}
```

to

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] result = greeting( scan );
    String fullname = result[0];
    String pinCode = result[1];
}
```

You have to assign the return value to an object and then you can get the values from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
String [] localResults = greeting(scan);
String fullname = results[0];
String pinCode = results[1];
```